# HTML Content Extraction Issue from Incoming Emails via GMail API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-api, gmail-api

Using the **GMail API**, I read the messages at the e-mail addresses I specified among my incoming e-mails. My problem here is that some of the messages in the incoming e-mails come to my variable as html pages. How can I get only the content of the message here? If the content of the e-mail contains only text, it receives it directly, but if there is an image, it turns it into an html page. Is this a problem or can I prevent it? I list the e-mails I receive on a page called "incoming e-mails" and I will show their content in detail.

```
public async Task<List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string>>> ReadEmails()
{
....
var emailListResponse = await emailListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
if (emailListResponse.Messages != null)
{
    foreach (var emailSummary in emailListResponse.Messages)
    {
        var emailInfo = await service.Users.Messages.Get("me", emailSummary.Id).ExecuteAsync();
        var emailSender = emailInfo.Payload.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Name == "From")?.Value;
        string emailAddress = emailSender.Contains("hello@info.mubi.com") ? "hello@info.mubi.com" :
              emailSender.Contains("contact@roonlabs.com") ? "contact@roonlabs.com" :
              "unknown";
        var emailSubject = emailInfo.Payload.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Name == "Subject")?.Value;
        var emailDate = emailInfo.Payload.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Name == "Date")?.Value;

        string emailBody = "";
        if (emailInfo.Payload.Parts == null && emailInfo.Payload.Body != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailInfo.Payload.Body.Data))
        {
            string base64EncodedBody = emailInfo.Payload.Body.Data;
            base64EncodedBody = base64EncodedBody.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/");
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedBody);
            emailBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        }
        else if (emailInfo.Payload.Parts != null)
        {
            foreach (var part in emailInfo.Payload.Parts) //metin, html, ekler vs varsa çok parçalı olarak kontrol edilmesi gerekiyor
            {
                if (part.MimeType == "text/plain" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(part.Body.Data))
                {
                    string base64EncodedBody = part.Body.Data;
                    base64EncodedBody = base64EncodedBody.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/");
                    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedBody);
                    emailBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        emailDetails.Add(Tuple.Create(emailInfo.Id, emailAddress, emailSender, emailSubject, emailBody, emailDate));
    }
}
return emailDetails;
}
```

If the content of incoming e-mails contains anything other than text, I do not know whether it should be an HTML page or not. When I receive text, I transfer the text to my database as it is, but if there is an image, it is saved as an html page.

Comment: Well, while dealing with emails via API, extracting the message content requires understanding their MIME structure, which often includes multiple parts for text, HTML, and images. To get just the text message, iterate through email parts, extract text from "text/plain" parts, and handle "text/html" parts by parsing them with an HTML parser to retain specific text while ignoring images.  Even, you could ignore any specific part that you don't want to extact or display.

Comment: You can fetch and parse the HTML with AngleSharp . Here is a link you can follow https://code-maze.com/csharp-parsing-html-with-anglesharp